# Getting This webpage is not available response when starting up node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner at node.js, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong when trying to access my server. Here are the things I wrote in cygwin to start up the server:

1) npm install http-server -g

2) http-server

Now, I access the server at http://0.0.0.0:8080, but it isn't working; it gives a "This webpage is not available" error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Please, don't hesitate to ask for more information if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with `http-server -a 127.0.0.1` and try accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8080` or `http://localhost:8080`

`0.0.0.0` is not a good default and doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the console type

```
 http-server -a 127.0.0.1
```

then in the browser try:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

or

```
 http://localhost:8080
```

be aware of have a index.html in the curren dir